# fetch data between two dates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I Am trying to extract all the previous days  data from google spreadsheet, When i hardcode the dates the data comes in perfectly but when i try to make it more dynamic so that i can automate the process it does not work.
This is what i tried, if someone can help

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime
from dateutil import parser

sheet_id = "19SzfcL3muVeISycG5eFYUqwrwwReGETZsNtl-euGU"
sheet_name = "October-2022"
url=f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}"
ct = datetime.datetime.today()
pt= datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
#print(ct)
#print(pt)
   
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df['Timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

#filtered_df = df.loc[(df['Timestamp1'] > '2022-10-13') & (df['Timestamp1'] < '2022-10-14')]
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['Timestamp1'] > 'pt') & (df['Timestamp1'] < 'ct')]
filtered_df
```

Comment: Hi Francis, I cannot access the data you provided at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19SzfcL3muVeISycG5eFYUqwrwwReGETZsNtl-euGU/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=October-2022 , can you check if sharing has been allowed / provide other link for a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

When you filter the dataframe you are comparing the Timestamp with a string variable. The solution you provided should be correct if you remove the quotation marks:

```
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['Timestamp1'] > pt) & (df['Timestamp1'] < ct)]
```